# Oauth through curl

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I search through google and also with keyword e.g. site:stackoverflow.com, but I do not find relevant solutions that answer my problem. I suppose it's because there are several issues bumping together.

My problem:
I have a deployed Google Cloud Functions. And I can successfully use gcloud obtaining identify token (through the steps 1. gcloud auth login 2. gcloud set project  3. gcloud auth print-identity-token) to access that deployed Google Cloud Functions without a problem.

However, there is a new requirement that an external client also wants to access to that Google Cloud Functions, but through curl (or RESTful plain http style). Now the problem raises. When following the link [1],

- I do not know the client_id and client_secret because the deployed Google Cloud Functions is a service account, which looks like no client_id and client_secret. I tried using the client_id, and client_secret found in legacy credential adc.json. But the curl responds a html doc like

  The document has moved [here](https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/error?authError=...)

I can auth by clicking the link in the browser, but that misses the purpose to auth in a non-interactive way.

- Don't know the exact parameter to refresh to token, but I suppose this is because I do not use the correct client_id and client_secret.

I appreciate any suggestions and comment. Many thanks!

[1]. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

Comment: This documentation link might help you getting started with this requirement: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Comment: @SrinathMenon Thanks. I tried that but didn't succeed. Should be something I did it wrong at my side. May look at it again later on. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround, but it works for my current requirement. I understand this may not be the correct answer. But I hope it would be of help if someone runs into similar issue.

1. Create client_id, client_secret, and refresh_token

   ```
   gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
   ```
2. Refresh token

   ```
   curl -s https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token  \
       -d client_id=$client_id \
       -d client_secret=$client_secret \
       -d refresh_token=$refresh_token \
       -d grant_type=refresh_token
   ```

The step one will create an `application-default.json`  file, which stores `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `refresh_token`, in gcloud setting's folder.

Then at the step 2, one can retrieve the refreshed token by ripping the value in response json, and use it  the call to the cloud functions deployed in Google env.

The doc I use as reference is https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_7